# Can I make VC++ Intellisense ignore some things it considers invalid?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

C++, VS 2012 (but the same thing happened in previous versions of VS).

Sometimes, the Intellisense finds "problems" that aren't really problems and puts its red squigglies under perfectly valid code.

Example:

```
class A {
  A(const A&);
  A& operator=(const A&);
public:
  A(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, int);
#define AMsg(x) A(x, __FILEW__, __LINE__)
};

...

throw AMsg(L"abc");
```

The AMsg macro converts into a ctor call, saving one typing the obvious last two parameter values, the code works as expected, yet the Intellisense puts a red squiggly under AMsg saying that A::A(const A&) is inaccessible. A::A(const A&) is inaccessible, yes, but AMsg calls a different ctor, and the Intellisense fails to see that.

Is there a way to somehow make the Intellisense just ignore AMsg? I remember we could, for example, edit the keyword list for the editor which was stored in a file, maybe there is some file or macros (e.g., a "do not parse the contents of this particular file" one?) that helps control the Intellisense?

Comment: It is a correct diagnostic, the copy constructor is needed to propagate the exception object to code that catches it.  That the compiler can optimize this away in certain cases is an implementation detail.

Comment: @Hans Passant: You are right, I used a bad example. Thanks for this. The question, however, still stands, as there are other cases where Intellisense gets things wrong.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Intellisense now has an excellent compiler, and the usual SO advice applies here too: Barring proof to the contrary, assume that the error is on your side and not the compilers'

Comment: Right now, I am staring at the code that defines two structure types with the same name in different compilation units, and the Intellisense in one of these units takes the definition of the type from the other unit. I can't reproduce this in a bare-bones project that only contains code relevant to the problem so some other code must be interfering, but (a) I can see that the code is correct (references a correct structure member), (b) the compiler can see that the code is correct, yet (c) the Intellisense can't see that the code is correct and complains. (contd)

Comment: It *is* possible that the code surrounding the one that the Intellisense complains about is wrong and that the compiler only compiles it by accident, but that seems a bit far fetched. I would agree though that the Intellisense in VS 2012 works much, much better than it worked in all previous versions of VS.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that the Intellisense compiler is built on top of EDG's compiler, not MSVC itself. EDG's compiler is far closer to the standard, which means that it catches problems today which MSVC might catch next year.

Intellisense can't be turned on or off on parts of your code base. That just doesn't make sense. Assume it would ignore `int foo(int)` and then the compiler would include `int foo(int)` in overload resolution. Your whole program could change.

Comment: Thanks. I can certainly see how turning the Intellisense off on some heavily referenced part of the code would reduce its usefulness to the developer, but I think turning it off for a particular function call or macro (that is, not autocompleting inside that call or macro, and not squiggling anything due to the number / types of arguments) wouldn't be quite so bad. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @MitchParker: As Raymond Chen puts it, every feature starts out at -100 points. And this feature scores extra penalty points for being hard to spec in a useful manner. Considering finite resources and limited benefits, I fully understand why there's no finer-grained control.